# Why in Java, ("string").equals(var) recommended other than (var).equals("string")?

Tags: java

I have seen most cases developers use first string and after that variable used in `.equal` operation. What is the reason?

Comment: @JqueryLearner well, that "handling" is the problem :D

Comment: @JqueryLearner Using `RuntimeException` to check values is absolutly not a good thing. So, always `"String".equals(var)`. If you need to know if var is null, just test it. As you will do when you write `var.equals("String")` because it's not a good thing to let a `NPE` happens when you can avoid it.

Comment: Because speak like Yoda, programmers do.

Answer (score 9):

Because var can be `null` and var.equals("string") will throw NullPointerException (attempt to call of method on null). On the other hand, `"string".equals(null)` will just return false.

Answer (score 4):

> why in Java, (“string”).equals(var) recommended other than (var).equals(“string”)?

This is because you do not know for sure what is var pointing to. It may very well be null because of which you may get NPE which will kill your current Thread. So 2nd approach is preferred as `(“string”).equals(var)` returns false.

For example consider you getting this var in your servlet

```
String var = request.getParameter("myvar");
if(var.equals("myVarValue")) {
//do something
}
```

This will throw NPE if parameter is not coming in your request.

Answer (score 3):

Because if var is null you won't raise a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void badOne() {
    String s = null;
    System.out.println(s.equals("abc"));
    // This function will throw null pointer
}

public static void goodOne() {
    String s = null;
    System.out.println("abc".equals(s));
    // This will print false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use ("string").equals(var), since it may show that the programmer does not know if var might be null or not. I would document if a var can be null or not and check it.

Example:

```
String makeAString(@NonNull String aStringValue) {
    Validate.notNull(aStringValue, "aStringValue must not be null");
    if (aStringValue.equals("abcde") {
       return "fg";
   } else {
       return "de";
   }
}

String makeAString(@Nullable String aStringValue) {
    if (aStringValue == null) {
       return "kl";
    }
    if (aStringValue.equals("abcde") {
       return "fg";
    } else {
       return "de";
    }
}
```

Comment: That assumes that you have control over the contents of the string, which isn't always the case. Although in principle I agree, if at all possible you should simply ensure that it's never null to begin with.